Is my calculation of the number of functions for  (    ,  ,  ) and  (    ,  ,  ) correct?
I’m working on a problem involving dynamic programming in graphs. The sub-path (ABC) has vertex weights and edge lengths, and we are tasked with calculating the optimal cost of a (k)-center.
Given (k = 1), I believe the total number of functions (F(ABC, r, 1)) and (G(ABC, r, 1)) is 14. This is based on the range of (r) (distance from (C)), which can take values (0, 1, 2, \dots, 6) for each function.
Here’s how I derived the functions:

Functions for (F(ABC, r, 1)):
(F(ABC, 0, 1), F(ABC, 1, 1),....., F(ABC, 6, 1)) (7 in total)

Functions for (G(ABC, r, 1)):
(G(ABC, 0, 1), G(ABC, 1, 1),....., G(ABC, 6, 1)) (7 in total)


Thus, the total is (7 + 7 = 14).
Could someone confirm if this reasoning is correct? Are there any errors in my argument or interpretation of the problem?
Thank you

Please transcribe text and mathematics instead of using an image as an important part of your post.
